# SpatialLocator.GetDefault() returns null

Tags: visual-studio, hololens

While trying to create my first AR application for HoloLens I created a HoloGraphicApp project right from VisualStudio2017. On running the app without applying changes to the code the app fails and gives an error message that reads

> 'Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.'

at the following code:

```
locator = SpatialLocator.GetDefault();
locator.LocatabilityChanged += this.OnLocatabilityChanged; //Error occurs here
```

I found out that `SpatialLocator.GetDefault();` returns `null` although the MSDN reference does not say that this method return `null`.

Does someone has an idea what is going on here?
Searching the web didn't bring a result.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have to create directly from VisualStudio?  Apologies that this is not a real answer, but especially for a first hololens app, I would recommend if at all possible following the more common development path: using Unity.  There is little support/resource for developing on hololens directly from Visual Studio, as the 3D engine of Unity is useful for almost every kind of project.  There are plenty of [resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/academy) available if Unity can be used.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No, I dont have to create directly from VS. I just thought, HoloLens is a Microsoft product so it should work with VS. But you are right I will go with Unity, because I didn't find any support from Microsoft on that.